# Not able to perform segue back using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, segue

I have started working with segue to perform navigation between viewcontrollers. This is how i was performing push segue from **EPSearchResultController** to destination viewcontroller.

```
   //.h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) EPSearchResultController *obj_EPFirstViewController;

    //.m File

    - (IBAction)submitEPSearchQuery:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"searchResultSegue" sender:sender];
}


    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"searchResultSegue"])
    {
        self.obj_EPFirstViewController = (EPSearchResultController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        self.obj_EPFirstViewController.searchAgainDelegate = self;
        NSDictionary* resultDict= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"SearchResult" ofType:@"plist"]];
        self.obj_EPFirstViewController.searchResultArray = [resultDict objectForKey:@"Result"];
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

When i am moving back from my destination to EPSearchResultController its showing me black screen. I am moving back by using

```
#pragma mark - Search Again Delegate

-(void)moveBack{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Anybody having any idea why its showing me a black screen.

Comment: What type of segue is searchResultsSegue? Is it a push segue or modal?

Comment: As i have mentioned it is a PUSH Segue.

Comment: found out the problem see my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

1) Check presentation style of a segue in Storyboard. It can be:

- Push
- Modal
- Custom

2) Use correct dismiss method.
if Push, use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`
if Modal, `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:];`

Comment: Why don't you use default back navigation button?

Comment: found out the problem see my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support...from your answers i got the idea that there is some problem with segue formation. I found it out that i made segue from button on EPSearchResultController to destination viewcontroller. But it should be from EPSearchResultController to destination viewcontroller. :-)

Comment: Ah! Yeah, if you're running the segue with code `performSegueWithIdentifier` then it needs to be from the VC to VC. You could just remove your IBAction code and just have the segue set up from the button. It will do the same thing.